# How to set timer values in EJB scheduling?

Tags: java, ejb, ejbscheduler

Currently I am using following configuration to schedule my scheduler.

```
 @Schedule(second ="1/10", minute = "*", hour = "*")
 private void scheduleUser() {      
    try {
        new UserFacade().insertUserInfo();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in : " + e);
    }
 }
```

Now I want  to set timer value in run time not in hard coded way. Let say I have a bean call `Property` and it has a field called `frequency`.

Now I want to set values like `new Property().getFrequency()` for `EJB` scheduler.

Is there any way to do some thing like following?

```
 @Schedule(second =new Property().getFrequency(), minute = "*", hour = "*")
 private void scheduleUser() {      
    try {
        new UserFacade().insertUserInfo();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in : " + e);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not with annotations, no. You have to use programmatic timers (Java 7, EE7):

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

@Singleton
public class MyTimer {
    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Timeout
    public void timeout(Timer timer) {
        System.out.println("TimerBean: timeout occurred");
    }

    public void schedule(Date start, long intervalMilis) {
        try{
            timerService.createTimer(start, intervalMilis, "my timer");            
        } catch (EJBException|IllegalArgumentException|IllegalStateException ex)  {
            Logger.getLogger(MyTimer.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples004.htm for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Vegard's submitted answer except this one using ScheduleExpression.
More info [Beginning Java EE 7 book](http://books.google.com/books?id=MqjKLdZCnZIC&pg=PA273&lpg=PA273&dq=ScheduleExpression%20java%207&source=bl&ots=VEHnj-s84d&sig=0f60Dpda4H0wtGV4-ZPjD99TXL0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Lo-LUpOtDNTNkQer1oDIBQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=ScheduleExpression%20java%207&f=false)

```
import javax.ejb.ScheduleExpression;

@Singleton
public class MyTimer {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Timeout
    public void timeout(Timer timer) {
        System.out.println("TimerBean: timeout occurred");
    }

    public void schedule(String DOW, String H, String M, String S) {
        try{
            ScheduleExpression scheduleExpression = new ScheduleExpression();
            scheduleExpression.dayOfWeek(DOW); 
            scheduleExpression.hour(H); 
            scheduleExpression.minute(M); 
            scheduleExpression.second(S); 

            timerService.createCalendarTimer(scheduleExpression, new TimerConfig(this, false));
        } catch (EJBException|IllegalArgumentException|IllegalStateException ex)  {
            Logger.getLogger(MyTimer.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

}
```